# How can I edit video (specifically mp4) metadata?

Tags: video, metadata, mp4, multimedia

I have a few video files that are 1080p video files, but for some reason, they don't have any metadata for bitrates (audio, video, or total) or anything like that. I first noticed this when I looked at the files in the Content view of the Windows 8.1 File Explorer. I used MediaInfo to obtain these values, so how can I add this metadata to the video files?

Answer (score 1):

You can try re-generating the MP4 with [MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/):

```
MP4Box -add input.mp4 -new output.mp4
```

It won't reencode the audio/video content, so will not change the quality, just repackage the streams and recompute some metadata. You can also add your own additional metadata if you want (iTunes tags, ...).